# itertools aparent bug with pygraphviz and return chain to flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, python-itertools, pygraphviz

I am finding a possible bug with chaining several methods in a return statement in flask.  I wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions on how to get around this problem.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flask
import time
from itertools import chain
from pygraphviz import AGraph

class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        G = ''

    def worker(self):
    a='1234'
        b=a + '45\n'
        yield b
        time.sleep(3)
        yield a

    def worker2(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        c = '\n9876'
        yield c

    def graph(self):
        G = AGraph(overlap='false')

tc = TestClass()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def test_method_get_stuff():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test_method_post_stuff():
    def test_method_sub_function():
    return chain(tc.worker(), tc.worker2(),tc.graph())
    return flask.Response(test_method_sub_function(),mimetype= 'text/plain')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Once a post is requested the `tc.worker()` and `tc.worker2()` generators return correctly but once it tries to perform `tc.graph()` it errors out with the below error.

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2014 18:23:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2014 18:23:18] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 691, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 81, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `tc.graph` doesn't `return` or `yield` anything explicitly, so will implicitly `return None`, which you can't iterate over. What were you expecting to get back from it? Also, `return flask.Response(...)` will never be reached.

Comment: I was expecting it to create a graph object. , return flask.response is actually indented but i screwed up the initial post

Comment: But it just assigns that to the local variable (note: not an instance attribute) `G`, then does nothing with it. Should it `return` the graph?

Comment: man, got to stop screwing up.  in reality its a variable of my class so tc.G in stead of just G, so i wasn't returning anything. However, your note helped me get around my problem.  In order to get around this, for methods I am not yielding anything, i place a yield '' in those methods and it allows my code to execute..  Thanks!